# Angular Unit Testing using Mock Models

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test a component. I need to set a variable on that component to an instance of PolicyMock, which is a mock I created from a model.

Example of Policy (real model)

```
export class Policy {

    businessArea: BusinessArea;
    statusCode: number;
    submittedStatus: SubmittedStatus;
    // ...
}
```

Example of the model I made, PolicyMock:

```
export class PolicyMock extends Policy {
    businessArea: 2;
    statusCode: -1;
    submittedStatus: 1;
    // ...
}
```

Now, I am not used to this heavy Object Oriented programming, I come from Javascript and React mainly. So it is likely some lack of understanding on my part, but when I try to set the variable in the component to an instance of my Mock model and console out those results I get this instead of the actual values within the class:

```
[PolicyMock{}]
```

Here is how I am trying to get set the variable (it's a private method so I am using the escape hatch syntax)

```
let cp: DataTableComponent<Policy>;
cp = new DataTableComponent<Policy>(sanitize, ref);
cp['data'] = [new PolicyMock()];
console.log(cp['data']);
```

I've also tried setting cp['data'] as an empty array intially and pushing the instance to it but that yielded the same result.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your PolicyMock definition basically says that `businessArea` could be just 2 (as a type) but doesn't do an initialization itself. You need to create a constructor and assign a real value to that property, or define it as `businessArea = 2` (not `businessArea: 2`). In other words `new PolicyMock()` makes just an empty object.

Comment: And you generally don't use a mock to provide data. You use a mock to simulate a behavior, i.e. to replace a method that does something by a method that does something simpler (like always return a given value). Just create a real instance of Policy with the data you want for your test.

Comment: @isevcik That worked thanks man!